# zsh: command not found: rabbitmq-server

Tags: rabbitmq, zsh

I've been following the RabbitMQ [installation guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html) via homebrew.

It says to add a line to my `.bash_profile`, but since I'm using [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) for my terminal I'm guessing I have to edit my `.zshrc` file.

I've tried adding the following possibilities:

- `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`
- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`
- `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`

Unfortunately none of them worked.

Elsewhere in the `.zshrc` file I see this line: `export ZSH=/Users/robinkim/.oh-my-zsh`. This may give a clue as to what needs to be added.

**EDIT: I simply forgot to `brew link rabbitmq`**

Comment: After editing `.zshrc`, did you start a new shell or re-`source` the file?

Comment: doh.. apparently I forgot to run `brew link rabbitmq` after installation. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as said in the edit you must type `brew link rabbitmq` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to run

`brew services start rabbitmq`